# Solr - NGramFilterFactory dont works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

I am trying configure my Solr (with sunspot, rails), to works like this:

Given a name: Willie Price
I want be able to search for: llie (for exemple)

On my schema.xml I added:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My Rails model:

```
  searchable do
    text :name, :as => :ngram
  end
```

I also try just:

```
  searchable do
    text :name
  end
```

On my controller:

```
 @search = Client.search do
    keywords params[:search]
 end
```

And also try this:

```
  @search = Client.search do
    full_text params[:search]
  end
```

The problem: I just be able to search using complete word, so given "Willie Price" only works with Willie or Price.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you restart Solr and re-index your documents after making this change?

Comment: Very strange. I just point the solr to my remote server and it works great. Maybe something related with sunspot_solr running locally...